# Airflow dag hanging on running state when interacting with AWS S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Simple Airflow DAGs are working for me, however, when I try to interact with an S3 bucket, the DAG will just hang on a running state. I'm using airflow S3 hook. If I run the code it will work but as a DAG it hangs. The function interacts with an API and saves the json file to an S3 bucket. Add your own bucket name to try the function out.

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook
import requests
import json


def dump_json_to_s3(url, bucket_name, file_name):
    """

    :param url: api
    :param bucket_name: s3 bucket name
    :param file_name: json file name
    :return:
    """

    try:
        print("Begin process ...")

        # Retrieve JSON file from API
        response = requests.get(url=url)

        # S3 key path
        key_path = f"asset/{file_name}.json"

        # Initialise hook
        hook = S3Hook('s3_conn')

        print(response.text)

        hook.load_string(
            string_data=response.text,
            key=key_path,
            bucket_name=bucket_name,
            replace=True
        )

        # Log a success message
        print(f"Success: JSON object has been uploaded to {key_path} S3 key path.")

    # Exceptions
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        # Log an error message
        print(f"Request Error: {e}")
    except boto3.exceptions.S3UploadFailedError as e:
        # Log an error message
        print(f"S3 Upload Error: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        # Log an error message
        print(f"Unexpected Error: {e}")

    return

# If you want to try the function without the DAG you can run below
url = "http://engineering-exam.s3-website.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/"
bucket_name = "INSERT YOUR S3 BUCKET NAME"

dump_json_to_s3(url=url, bucket_name=bucket_name, file_name='asset_new')
```

DAG below

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dump_json_to_s3_file import *


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 9, 1),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='dump_to_s3',
    schedule_interval=None,
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False
)

convert_json = PythonOperator(
    task_id="convertor",
    python_callable=dump_json_to_s3,  # Reference the function without calling it
    op_args=[  # Provide arguments as a list if needed
        "http://engineering-exam.s3-website.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/",
        "INSERT YOUR S3 BUCKET NAME",
        "airflow_tester"
    ],
    dag=dag
)

convert_json
```

Comment: What do the task logs show?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use boto3 instead of S3Hook (you may meet other problem, but boto3 should work)

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

s3_bucket = 'test'
s3_key = 'abc'
local_file = 'xx.json'
client.upload_file(local_file, s3_bucket, s3_key)
```

Add above code in a python function and trigger it with a PythonOperator.

Comment: Originally I had used boto3 but had the same issue. I had read airflow hooks as the way to interact with AWS DAGS. But both have the same issue.

Comment: How do you trigger your dag? I see schedule_interval=None, do you trigger it manually in UI?

Comment: It seems airflow dag mechanism instead of s3 operation problem, could you check your dag with some other logic, like print every 5 min first? does that work well?

Comment: Yes I do trigger manually as a test. I have also created basic DAGs that just print text or perform addition and they work fine.

Comment: I've also created a DAG that just prints a pandas dataframe and it works. So the pandas package works with airflow

Comment: Is that possible related with aws token?  Not sure S3Hook, but boto3 needs aws token for client init

Comment: [S3Hook uses boto3 under the hood](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/s3.py#L18)

Comment: @RNHTTR yes, you are right, I guess it may be related with aws token, but aws token will return error instead of hang.. Have you tried your operation without airflow? at d789w